# React Cytoscape JS - Node positioning based on level

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js, eclipse-elk

I am using Elk layout of the React Cytoscape JS component.
The nodes are at three levels: 1.x; 2.x; 3.x;
The layout runs from left to right.
I would like all the 3.x to be aligned in the same column.
The sandbox code link is given below.

What are my options to do this?

- force the node position?
- add a hidden node?
- use a transform?
- other?

Which of the above options is my low hanging fruit for a large graph read from a spreadsheet?
A snippet solution is appreciated!

[image: layout without alignment]
[Sandbox Code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-cytoscape-forked-z553mw?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A29%2C53)